# How to set id for each filed in form group?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, formbuilder, formgroups

I'm using angular and I need check id of each input. Is there any way to set id form each form input like this?

```
this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstname: ['', {id: 1}],
  lastname: ['', {id: 2}],
  email: ['', {id: 3}]
)}
```

Comment: May I know the reason why you set `id`? What do you mean check id for each input?

Comment: You can not write this code (a formGroup is a FormGroup of FormControls, and a FormControl has **no** id). In Angular really you needn't any "id". You get the value of the formGroup, and this value is the value you show in the "inputs". What are you try to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but you shouldn't use the `FormGroup` configuration for this. `FormGroup` has no support for setting the id attribute.

You can assign the id attribute of an input like this:

```html
<input [id]="'my-id'" />
```

So you have to either hardcode the ids into the template, or use some other form of configuration than `FormGroup` to get it from like a dictionary object.

Comment: Seems more like a comment than a solution.

Comment: It answers the question, right? Is the question properly formulated?

Comment: It didn't answer the question until your edit 10 mins ago.